# Есть ли в kotlin аналог eval в python

Tags: kotlin, eval

Мне нужно решить подобный пример: "5+6*8", он щаписан в виде строки, в python я бы сделал так: eval("5+6*8"), можно ли что то подобное сделать в kotlin?

Comment: через ScriptEngineManager можно

Comment: Дело не в Котлине, а в среде исполнения. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/eval.html

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin это только язык, сам язык такой функциональности не имеет, зато среда в которой исполняется транслируемый код или байтокод может иметь нужные функции.

В случае исполнения на JVM можно использовать интерпретатор javascript из поставки JVM:

```
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn")
engine.eval("5+6*8")
```

Этот интерпретатор js обещают выкинуть из будущих версий JVM, но в последний LTS версии JVM 11 он есть.

В случае трансляции Kotlin в javascript для исполнения его в броузере либо в Node.js нужно просто использовать функцию `eval(expr: String)`

Ну а если требуется все сделать самостоятельно, без использования готовых интерпретаторов, то подобные математические выражения можно вычислять посредством преобразования в обратную польскую нотацию с последующим вычислением на стековой машине, там алгоритм довольно простой.